# About ImageBase of .EXE in windows

Tags: exe, portable-executable

I just learned `ImageBase` is specified in PE format,and OS will load it to the exact position for `.EXE` , then comes the question:

what if two `.EXE` is requiring the same `ImageBase` location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase of 2 EXE's, they have Completely Different Address Spaces...Every Executable has its own space. 
This means, every time you execute an EXE, it is assigned its own independent `4GB` (on 32bit systems, although the process can use just part of it, the rest goes the kernel.) worth address space. It's [Virtual Address Space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912(VS.85).aspx). It's different from your Physical Memory.

So there's no conflict.

Technically, a PE can load just about anywhere, but the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) `ImageBase` is `0x400000`.

Now, Lets say you have an EXE and it loads a couple of DLL's (which happen to have the same ImageBase)...In this case, The first DLL loads fine, the second one gets relocated (or "rebased"). Each DLL has a `.reloc` Section which contains data about updating references within the code.

Comment: How can there be no conflict when both `EXE` are loaded to `0x4000000`?

Comment: @StOle,what about the address in visual studio's "Disassembly Window", is it virtual address or physical memory?

Comment: @harper, It's Virtual. Think about it this way, Processes will have 4GB Address spaces even if you have `256MB` RAM. This is possible because of Virtual Memory (/Paging).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)  to see the value the ImageBase and Base addresses of any running application (with its DLLs). Based on these values you can see whether rebasing has taken place.