# section header location in an exe

Tags: windows, executable, exe, portable-executable

Does the following code indicate that in an exe, the section header comes after the section itself, or am I missing on something? 
Also the value of lpFileBase is diffent from the value held in pimnth->OptionalHeader.ImageBase. Aren't they supposed to be the same??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<WinNT.h>


int main()
{


HANDLE  hFile,hFileMapping;
LPVOID lpFileBase;
LPVOID lp;
long offset;

if((hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("c:\\linked list.exe"),GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    std::cout<<"unable to open";

if((hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL)) == 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    std::cout<<"unable to open for mapping";
}

if((lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0))== 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    std::cout<<"couldn't map view of file";
}

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pimdh;
pimdh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFileBase;

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pimnth;
pimnth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(pimdh->e_lfanew + (char *)lpFileBase);


PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pimsh;
pimsh = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pimnth + 1);



printf("Address of section header:%x\n",pimsh);

for(int i = 0; i<pimnth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
{
    if(!strcmp((char *)pimsh->Name,".text"))
    {
        printf("Virtual Address:%x\n\n\n",pimsh->VirtualAddress);
    }
    pimsh++;
}

}
```

Comment: [About ImageBase of .EXE in windows][1] answers this question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740976/about-imagebase-of-exe-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

The value (address) contained in the OptionalHeader.ImageBase field is placed by the compiler/linker. This predefined address is needed by the linker in order to be able to calculate the jumps and the offset when variables and functions are invoked. One of the very first task of the loader is to verify whether this predefined address is already occupied in memory (which is often the case for DLLs). Should the address NOT be occupied, then your lpFileBase would be the same as OptionalHeader.ImageBase.